# Вывод json из базы mysqli

Tags: php, json, mysqli

Есть ячейка в которую записываю json:

[image]

Хочу разобрать json и вывести его делаю так:

```
$json = json_decode($db['json_data'], true);
//var_export($json);
$text = $json['1']['text'];
```

В итоге русские символы выводит как: **u044bu0432u0430u044bu0432u0430**

Как это исправить?

**UPD1:** в ячейке json_data вот такой json:

```
{"1":{"text":"u044bu0432u0430u044bu0432u0430"}}
```

записываю я его так:

```
json_encode($json)
```

**UPD2:** покуда решил это записью русских символов как есть, то есть без кодировки:

```
json_encode($json, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)
```

Comment: а вам точно `var_export` нужен а не `var_dump` ?

Comment: @teran мне нужно вывести просто текст, я делаю так: `$text = $json['1']['text'];` в итоге русские символы выводит как **u044bu04**

Comment: @teran обновил вопрос

Comment: выводит он то что есть. юникод строка должна выглядеть как `\u044b\u0432...`